# Find a dynamic added tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic-data, traversal

I am trying to see how to find a tag that was added dynamically within a table as so:

```
ParentTag= document.getElementById('parentdiv');
var newTag = document.createElement('div');
newTag.innerHTML="<span class="ImNew"></span>" 
ParentTag.appendChild(newTag);
```

How will I be able to find that tag in **javascript**, not leaning towards using jquery so no **live** recommendations please.. Trying to find that new tag in strictly javascript.

The tag I am referring to is the **span** tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what other elements exist in the element. You can for example get all span tags in the element and filter out the ones with a specific class name:

```
var parentTag = document.getElementById('parentdiv');
var spans = parentTag.getElementsByTagname('SPAN');
var filtered = [];
for (var i=0; i<spans.length; i++) {
  if (spans[i].className === 'ImNew') filtered.push(spans[i]);
}
```

If there is only one span tag with that class name in the element, the `filtered` array now cotnains a reference to that element.

Comment: well when I look at the view source, that added span element is not there, but the content within it is displayed on the page, so are you sure I would be able to find it by just traversing the span tags

Comment: @Jake that's your browser showing you the page source rather than the current contents of the DOM. If you inserted it, it will be there.

Comment: You can use Firebug to see the actual contents of the DOM in real time, which would be a big help.

Answer (score 2):

You could give your new tag an ID when you create it:

```
ParentTag= document.getElementById('parentdiv');
var newTag = document.createElement('div');
newTag.setAttribute('id','myNewID');
newTag.innerHTML="<span class="ImNew"></span>" 
ParentTag.appendChild(newTag);
```

Then later, just use that ID to find it:

```
var newTag = document.getElementById('myNewID');
```

Comment: sorry, if I mislead you, but I would be trying to find that span tag

Comment: OK, was not clear on that. Can you still use the same technique of finding it by ID, or is that no good for your needs?

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, why not just keep track of it or give it an `id` if you're going to need it later?

But anyway, this is how you could do a manual search (searching from back to front as you're adding the new items to the end).

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parentdiv")
for (var i = parent.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var el = parent.childNodes[i];
    if (el.nodeType == 1 &&
        el.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "div" &&
        el.firstChild &&
        el.firstChild.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "span" &&
        el.firstChild.className = "ImNew")
    {
        // el.firstChild is what you want
    }
}
```